# Can not convert caf fomat to m4a format

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, ios7

I use follow code to convert caf format to m4a format and save to another directory of Iphone, it works in IOS6 with Xcode 4.6.3, but when I updated to Xcode 5, it is not working anymore. And if if use IOS6 simulator in Xcode 5, it works again.

```
-(void)saveFile {
    NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    outputFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i.m4a", currentCueIndex + 1000]]];
}
```

So I am wondering is it a bug of IOS 7 or Apple changed somethings?

Thanks

**Updated**

```
AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:recordedTmpFile options:nil];
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionTrackA = [mixComposition     addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] lastObject];

[compositionTrackA insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)  ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter =[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

[self saveFile];


NSParameterAssert(exporter!=nil);
exporter.outputFileType=AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
exporter.outputURL=outputFile;
// Subtract a fraction of a second so the first word isn't chopped off
clipStartTime = clipStartTime - kSilenceBeforeFirstAudio;

CMTime start=CMTimeMake(clipStartTime * 100, 100);
CMTime duration=CMTimeMake(clipDuration * 100, 100);
CMTimeRange range=CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
exporter.timeRange=range;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Where is your code where you convert the file, you just posted code for the file path.

Comment: I updated more codes. @rckoenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the problem.
Should replace this line

```
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:nil];
```

to

```
   [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        int exportStatus = exporter.status;
        switch (exportStatus) {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: {

                NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted--");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: {
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: {
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: {
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: {
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
                break;
            }
            default: { NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;}
        }

    }];
```